# Flutter: I can I build a list with different elements ex: a card with a text and a switch, an other card with a text and a slider

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I want to create a list with different elements eg: one card with a text and a switch, the other with a text and a slider.
I have been looking for how to do this for a week, but I cannot find. Can you help me please ?

Comment: List<dynamic> list;

Answer (score 0):

You can define a list of Widgets list this

```
List<Widget> list = [ItemWithCard(),ItemWithSwitch()];
```